# Is it safe to insert into crm database using sql?

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We need to insert data(`8k records`) into a `CRM Entity`, the data will come from other `CRM Entities`. Currently we are doing it through code but it takes too much time (`Hours`). I was wondering if we use `SQL` to insert directly into the `CRM Database` it will be a lot easier and will take only minutes. But before moving farward **I have few questions**:

1. Is it safe to insert directly into CRM Database, using SQL?
2. What is the best practice for insert data into CRM using SQL?
3. What things should i consider before  trying it?

**EDIT:**

4: How do I increase the insert performance?

Comment: How many records are you inserting that it takes hours?

Comment: Some 8k records. Some other steps are also involved like checking that the record not already exists!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, it is not. It is considered [unsupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928224.aspx)
2. Don't do it
3. Rollup 12 was just released and contains a new API feature. There is now a [`ExecuteMultipleRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest.aspx) which could be used for batched bulk imports. See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx

Comment: I didn't know about the ExecuteMultipleRequest.   I'm looking forward to using it.

Comment: @Daryl it was just released with the newest SDK and Rollup 12

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't take hours to insert 8000 records.  It would help to see your code, but here are some things to consider to improve performance:

1. Reuse your IOrganizationService.  I've found a 10x increase in performance by reusing a IOrganizationService, rather than creating a new one with each record that is being updated
2. Use multi-threading.  You have to be careful with this one, because it could lead to worse performance if the function to check for the entity existing is your bottle neck.
3. Tweak your exists function.  If the check for the entity existing is taking a long time, consider pulling back the entire table and storing it in memory (assuming it's not ridiculously huge).  This would remove 8000 separate select statements.
4. Turn off plugins that may be degrading performance.  If you have any plugins registered on the entity, see if performance increases if you disable them during the import.
5. Create a new, "How do I increase the insert performance" question with your code posted for additional help.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used the `CRM application` you are referring to, but if you bypass the code you might bypass certain restrictions or even triggers that the code has in place based on certain values sent in.

For example, if you sent a number in through the code, it might perform some mathematical function on that number and add it to some other value and end up storing two values in the database (one value for the number you entered, and another value representing the total including the newly added one).

So if you had just inserted the one value straight into the database, then the total wouldn't get updated with it.

That is just a hypothetical scenario. You may not run into any problems like that or any others, but there could be the chance.

Answer (score 3):

Well i found [this article](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/04/15/optimizing-sql-integrating-services-ssis-with-mscrm/) very helpful. **It says**:

The **direct SQL writes to CRM database are not supported**.The reason for this is that creating a record in CRM database is so much more than just `INSERT INTO…`-statement. The first step of optimizing is to understand what happens behind the scenes and can affect the speed:

**1.** CRM entities usually consist of 2 physical tables.

**2.** Cascade rules/Sharing: If created record has any relationships with
    cascade rules, web service will handle the cascades automatically.
    For example cascaded sharing will lead to additional records being
    created in PrincipalObjectAccess table. In case of one-time
    migrations, disabling the cascade rules while migration runs can
    save lot of time

**3.** Record Ownership: If you are inserting records, make sure you are
    setting the owner as an attribute for create and not as an
    additional owner assign request. Assigning owner actually takes

**4.** Money/Time: Web Service handles currencies and time zones.

**5.** Workflows/Plugins: If the system has any custom workflows and/or
    plugins, I strongly recommend pausing them for the duration of
    migration.